# Integrating my node.js module to express.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I made a module in node.js. Basically, this module grabs data from mongodb and returns a JSON value.

Now in Express.js, the front-end developer (not me) is using a jQuery plugin to do things. This jQuery needs a JSON variable as a parameter to do its thing.

Now, I have no idea how to send my JSON variable (which is generated server-side), to the jQuery plugin, which works client-side. I can't wrap my head around how to start doing this, so I'm having a hard time googling for it. No idea what the keywords will be. So, both technical answers and a general explanation of how this work will be appreciated.

Comment: make an ajax request from the front end to a route on backend (e.g. /getmyjson)... on express, define this route, and send back the json value you get from you module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:
**Client side jQuery**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/request',
    data: {
        test: "test"
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(result){
            alert(result);
    },
    error : function(){
            console.log("error")
    }
});
```

**In Node.js** 
Try the following server side code to handle `/request`:

```
app.get('/request', function(req, res){ 
      var data = {'TestKey':'TestValue'};
      //For test at server side only
      console.log('Sent this data to client:\n' + JSON.stringify(data)); 
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
      res.end(JSON.stringify(data)); 
});
```

---

**Update**: Instead of `res.writeHead..` & `res.end..` 
You can use also:

```
res.json(data);
```